# unable to open program using php

Tags: php

I have tried all exec, system and all but i am not able to open notepad even. I am using XAMPP on Windows 7.

> system("cmd /c notepad");

Comment: browser goes on loading and doesn't return back

Comment: @Mustafa You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5846492/edit) your question.

Comment: Demanding urgent help on a web forum, and allowing only 1 minute for an answer is both exceedingly rude, and very presumptuous. Of course there's millions of users out there in the rest of the world who have nothing better to do than wait around for someone like you to scream in their ear.

Comment: Of course it keeps loading. It's waiting for notepad to exit.

Comment: Am I wrong, or you want to execute an instance of notepad using PHP through a web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works here (notepad is opened), but you should realize two things:

- If you're running Apache as a service, you won't have a notepad windows pop up because the service will probably be running as another user in a non-interactive fashion.
- It's normal that you get no response for a long (perhaps indefinitely) because it will wait for the program to finish. See [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) or [`popen`](http://php.net/popen) for more control.

Comment: And of course, does the Apacher userID have permission to run anything in \windows?

Comment: so how should i allow apache user to rum any program?

Comment: by making it a super user (I guess that's administrator for windows)..but...I don't think you *really* wanna do that...

Comment: Services, unless configured otherwise, run under the System Account, which has very broad privileges.